# Can you end a sentence with a clitic like "they're"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I saw someone write the sentence "Of course they're". As a native English speaker, this instantly seemed wrong but I couldn't come up with a good reason as to why. I did a bit of research and there seems to be a rule called "stranding" where if there's an object before the clitic then it can't end like that but I don't entirely understand it.

Comment: Maybe there *is* a rule for that (I'm not really sure), but I have *never* heard anyone speak like that.

Comment: I looked up *clitic* and found: *A morpheme that functions like a word, but appears not as an independent word but always attached to a following or preceding word.*  That doesn't seem to describe *they're*.

Comment: Although it's clear to me this is a duplicate (*and* I agree with @Jim that it misuses the word "clitic"), I've upvoted alongside my closevote because I think it's an interesting question that deserves to be revisited from time to time.

Comment: @Jim: no, but it does describe *'re*. Or at least so I understand.

Comment: No, you can't. Cliticized contractions are for unstressed function words, not stressed sentence codas.